# Core Animation doesn't work. Object disappears

Tags: cocoa, core-animation, nsimageview

```
[animationImageView setWantsLayer:YES];

CAKeyframeAnimation *keyframeAnimation = [CAKeyframeAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"position"];    
keyframeAnimation.values = [animationsBindingsController valueForKeyPath:@"selection.controlPoints"];
keyframeAnimation.duration = 5;
[animationImageView.layer addAnimation:keyframeAnimation forKey:@"position"];
[pageContent addSubview:animationImageView];
```

`AnimationImageView` is a subclass of `NSImageView`.

`animationImageView` object disappears for a 5 seconds (for a duration of animation), and suddenly it appears in init position.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, Instead of subclassing NSImageView, I subclassed CALayer (by method setContents: you can set NSImage). Core Animation works perfectly!